# Make only part of a window scrollable in win32 api

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have created a working application with pure win32 APIs and C. It has a shared "status area" on top. Rest of the area displays device information (multiple fields per device).

How do I make the device information area only scrollable?

All my widgets are currently attached to single main window handle. See here the picture about what I want : [image: Example of how I want the scroll to be]

There must be a simple way to like group the widgets of bottom page and attach scrollbar to only the group, but I cannot seem to find a working technique with google. I guess my problem is I do not know hot to create groups of widgets or something. Attaching scrollbar to to the full window works fine but I want only partial.

For those interested: I'm using Dev-C++ 5.11 with TDM-GCC 4.9.2 . I don't have and won't have a resource editor. It is all in C code.

Help!

Edit1: Ok, I believe the correct term I need to search for is "child windows" per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#child-windows

Edi2: This old scavenged code worked somewhat: https://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/94197-creating-child-window-parent-window-post676608.html#post676608 . It creates ugly window inside window but it is what I need to get started.

[image: Old scavenged code yielding somewhat working results.]

Comment: I've done something like this.  Is UI above make with  .rc file?  Or are you manually creating the controls?  Can you post some code for your UI ?

Comment: Are your MAC/IP control within its own child HWND ?

Comment: *"There must be a simple way to like group the widgets of bottom page and attach scrollbar"* - There is: a window. Create one, set the `WS_VSCROLL` style, plus the `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` extended style. Otherwise keyboard navigation fails.

Comment: I think I tried earlier creating a window and placing another window there and a component in the subwindow. But it did not work. I will try again. I'm not using .rc files, everything is pure code. Children don't have their own HWNDs. Everything goes now "flat" to the same main window.

Comment: You have to handle `WM_VSCROLL` message in the child window and call `ScrollWindowEx()` to actually move the controls. Also have a look at `SetScrollRange` to set the virtual size of the child window (depending on the number of controls) and `SetScrollInfo` to update scroll position (which you have to do in response to `WM_VSCROLL`). These are just pointers, you will need to research the [whole topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/scroll-bars), it's not so trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i reduced the code into a minimum: https://gist.github.com/usvi/b39713e270f1f75880698baacd1774b4 or

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK HelloWndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
                    PSTR szCMLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("HelloApplication");
    HWND hwnd,hwnd2;
    MSG msg; 
    WNDCLASS wndclass;

    wndclass.style      = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = HelloWndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = sizeof(long);
    wndclass.hInstance  = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon      = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor    = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;

    if (!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("This program requires Windows 95/98/NT"),
                    szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }
    
    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,      
                        TEXT("Hello World for Windows"), 
                        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,    
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,      
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,      
                        400,        
                        400,
                        NULL,               
                        NULL,               
                        hInstance,          
                        NULL);              

    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    hwnd2 = CreateWindow(szAppName,     
                        TEXT("Hello World"), 
                        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,      
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,      
                        300,        
                        300,        
                        hwnd,               
                        NULL,               
                        hInstance,          
                        NULL);              

    ShowWindow(hwnd2, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd2);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}



LRESULT CALLBACK HelloWndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC     hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT    rect;

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            return 0;

        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC     hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT    rect;

    switch (message){
        case WM_CREATE:
            return 0;

        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

            DrawText(hdc, TEXT("Hello, Windows"), -1, &rect,
                    DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            return 0;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And it works, see:

[image: MVP window with scrollbars]

My problem basically was that child window creation CreateWindow() first parameter was omitted or otherwise wrong. It needs to match named and registered WNDCLASS.

**NOTE:** This is a rough rough rough sketch, I might need to make 2 classes and second message handler. But this is a good start.

Comment: Questions and answers need to be self-contained. Linking to external resources will inevitably render contributions useless.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes you are right, I also inlined the code.